# How to resize and position a map in Raphael js?

Tags: svg, raphael

I am trying to include a world map in a dynamicaly crreated div using Raphael js. Once the path is defined, I am updating rapahel paper object's viewbox to scale the path. Although this part is working, I am not able to align the path to the center of the div. The following is what I have done so far according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140786/raphael-path-resize-and-move-relative-to-container):

```
var paper = Raphael("map"),
            path = paper.path(w_path).attr({fill: "#000", "stroke-width": 0, "stroke-linejoin": "round", opacity: 1}),
    box = path.getBBox(),
            margin = Math.max(box.width, box.height) * 0.025;  // set the viewbox to match the bounding box of the path with 2.5% margins
    paper.setViewBox(box.x - margin, box.y - margin, box.width + margin * 2, box.height + margin * 2);
```

My question is how can I align the path at the center of the div (map div), both vertically and horizontally?

UPDATE:
I have added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22tQU/) for this.

Comment: Howdy.  Do you happen to have this staged somewhere (jsbin/jsfiddle)?  I'd be happy to take a look.