# Raphael transform resets my scale

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have the following rapheal javascript in my onload

```
var cmdShapeString = "M 0 0 l 20 0 2 5 10 0 2 -5 100 0 0 30 -100 0 -2 5 -10 0 -2 -5 -20 0z";
var R = Raphael("toolbox");
var path = R.path(cmdShapeString) ;
path.attr({stroke:"#777777", fill: "#CCCCCC"});
path.scale(0.5);    
//path.attr({x:-100, y: 0}); //Has no effect
path.transform("T"+0+","+0); //Resets the scale back to 1.0???
```

Originally when the path is drawn on the screen it is drawn at 0,0
[image: start]

Then I scale it to half size and it jumps to the left.

[image]

I then try to put it back to 0,0 with path.transform which resets the scale back to 1.0 it seems.
[image]

Trying to set the x and y using attr has absolutely no effect.

What is going on here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After I posted this on the right in the related section this came up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140786/raphael-path-resize-and-move-relative-to-container?rq=1  
Wondering if I should delete this question now or leave it as is :/

Comment: I'll leave it up for now. It does show nicely what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`path.scale(0.5);` is actually a shorthand for `path.transform('S0.5');` (or maybe lower case s I didn't check.

So it's not so surprising that this overwrites the transform attribute once you know that...

```
path.transform("T"+0+","+0); //Resets the scale back to 1.0???
```

Fortunately there is a workaround in the [raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform). Use t rather than T

```
path.transform("t"+0+","+0);
```